# add copied csv column data in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following with the following structure

```
1;test1;
2;test2;
3;test5;
```

I have to add new column from XLS file so that will be

```
test10
test11
test12
```

Now I am trying to append this column to the text file like

```
1;test1;test10
2;test2;test11
3;test5;test12
```

I tried

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>downarrow</kbd>

Then I pasted the column data of XLS but all the data is appending to the each row.

where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste the column you want to add into an empty notepad++ document, then select it while holding down <kbd>alt</kbd> (this will then copy it as a column of data, rather than a long string with line breaks in it).

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to copy.

Then switch back to the document you want to paste the column into, <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>down arrow</kbd> to select the lines to paste into and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste.